# Converting an NSArray of Dictionaries to JSON array in iOS

Tags: iphone, json, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I need to send an `NSArray` to the server in the `JSON` array format. How can I convert it to `JSON`. This is a sample of my `NSArray` that I have to pass.

```
array([0] => array('latitude'=>'10.010490', 
                  'longitude'=>'76.360779', 
                   'altitude'=>'30.833334', 
                  'timestamp'=>'11:17:23', 
                      'speed'=>'0.00', 
                   'distance'=>'0.00');

[1] => array('latitude'=>'10.010688', 
            'longitude'=>'76.361378', 
             'altitude'=>'28.546305', 
            'timestamp'=>'11:19:26', 
                'speed'=>'1.614', 
             'distance'=>'198.525711')
 )`
```

and the required format is like this

```
[
  { "latitude":"10.010490",
   "longitude":"76.360779",
    "altitude":"30.833334",
   "timestamp":"11:17:23", 
       "speed":"0.00",
    "distance":"0.00"
  },    
  {
   "latitude":"10.010688",
  "longitude":"76.361378",
   "altitude":"28.546305",
  "timestamp":"11:19:26",
      "speed":"1.614",
   "distance":"198.525711" 
  }
]
```

Any one have solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *firstJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"10.010490", @"latitude",
                            @"76.360779", @"longitude",
                            @"30.833334", @"altitude",
                            @"11:17:23", @"timestamp",
                            @"0.00", @"speed",
                            @"0.00", @"distance",
                            nil];

  NSDictionary *secondJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"10.010490", @"latitude",
                            @"76.360779", @"longitude",
                            @"30.833334", @"altitude",
                            @"11:17:23", @"timestamp",
                            @"0.00", @"speed",
                            @"0.00", @"distance",
                            nil];

NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr addObject:firstJsonDictionary];
[arr addObject:secondJsonDictionary];

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: It works for me but I want response in array format not in string format.

Comment: inline 'code [
  { "latitude":"10.010490",
   "longitude":"76.360779",
    "altitude":"30.833334",
   "timestamp":"11:17:23", 
       "speed":"0.00",
    "distance":"0.00"
  },    
  {
   "latitude":"10.010688",
  "longitude":"76.361378",
   "altitude":"28.546305",
  "timestamp":"11:19:26",
      "speed":"1.614",
   "distance":"198.525711" 
  }
] ' you will get it in Array format only

Answer (score 5):

**The simplest and best approach !!!**

To convert NSArray or NSMutableArray into jsonString you can first convert it into NSData and then further convert that into a NSString. Use this code

```
NSData* data = [ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It helped me and hope it helps you as well. All the best.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question title. Thanks. The accepted answer shows an array of dictionaries

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [SBJson-Framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).

Converting an `NSMutableArray` is as simple as `NSString *jsonString = [yourArray JSONRepresentation];`

Edit: Jack Farnandish is right u have to transform it into a NSDictionary before you can convert it to Json. In my example the NSMutableArray has to contain the Dictionary. The Array is only needed to create the square brackets at the beginning and the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [build in JSON functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of iOS or use an external lib e.g. [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to convert your data to JSON

Answer (score 2):

First You must change you structure into `NSDictionary` class and `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary` objects, then try JSONKit in iOS 5 serialization works better than standard `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <JSONKit/JSON.h>

NSArray *array = // Your array here.
NSString *json = [array JSONString];

NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) performs significantly better than [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) and others in my own and the author's benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) tutorial, JSON in iOS 5.0 was clearly explained (serailization, deserailization).

Answer (score 1):

Is the service you are calling a RESTful service?

If so, I'd strongly recommend using RestKit. It does object serialization/deserialization. It also handles all the networking underpinnings. Extremely valuable, and well maintained.

Comment: Using framework for such a simple task is not really a good idea. Update 2016 RestKit is not a maintained framework any more.