# Send multiple json data to server - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I need to send json data to the server. I am able to send json object to server. But i want to send multiple json object to server like below.

Json1:

```
{
 "Comments" : "test”,
 "user_id" : “test”,
 "EdDate" : "08\/26\/2015 03:16:58 PM",
 "StDate" : "08\/26\/2015 03:16:20 PM",
 "latitude" : "",
 "longitude" : "",
 "sample" : [
 {
  "quantity" : “1”,
 }
]  
}
```

Json 2:

```
{
 "Comments" : "test”,
 "user_id" : “test”,
 "EdDate" : "08\/26\/2015 04:11:51 PM",
 "StDate" : "08\/26\/2015 04:11:21 PM",
 "latitude" : "",
 "longitude" : "",
 "sample" : [
 {
   "quantity" : “1”,
 }
]
}
```

I need to send one by one. I am using the following code but only once i am getting the proper response.

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
for( int i=0 ; i < [tempJsonFromDB count]; i++)
{
        tempjsondata = [tempjsondata stringByAppendingString:tempJsonFromDB[i]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[tempjsondata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [mainQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:mainQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                                 NSData *urlData, NSError *requestError) 
        {
           NSString* newStr1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[urlData bytes]];
           NSLog(@“string%@“,newStr1);
        }];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
       [connection start];
}
```

Comment: could you please describe what happens with the rest of request , do you get an error in the completionHandler and if yes what is the error ?

Comment: is this your array tempJsonFromDB

Comment: @Abd Al-rhman Taher Badary First time i am getting "True" but after i am getting some web content.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik tempJsonFromDB is my exact json.

Comment: see this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299965/converting-an-array-into-json-array-in-ios

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't want to merge it. i want to send one by one.

Answer (score 0):

A view hints:

- This approach may only work with a small number of requests which are all enqueued at once, say up to 10.
- In order to avoid potential concurrency issues, set `[mainQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` to `1`. Note: currently there is no issue in your sample, but your production code will likely have to access some shared variable - where you might get a data race. Ensure that you use a dedicated serial queue where all accesses to that shared variable will be executed. (You might also dispatch to the main queue or a dedicated dispatch queue).

  Note, that this setting does not alter the number of concurrent active HTTP request, though. This is for the delegate(s) only.
- Print out ALL error messages in your delegate, as well the status code of the response and the Content-type header.
- When you print out the returned content from the server, consider that this might be HTML code with an arbitrary encoding. This is frequently the case when the server returned with a status other than 2xx - even you explicitly specified the `Accept` header. While this is a bug on the server side, you have to deal with it. Sadly, this is a quite common server behavor.
- You might improve the code using `NSURLSession`.
- If you have a large number of requests, you should improve your code utilising a third party library which is able to deal with a lot of concurrent requests.